# Preference changes only happen when restarting the app

Tags: android, checkbox, listener, sharedpreferences, changelistener

I was coding an app I added a preferences menu, and it works, but changes happen only when I restart the application,anyone knows how to make changes happen whithout exitting the app??? 
Thanks in advance ;)

My code ( from main activity):

```
preferencias = preferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(TimeToSpeechActivity.this);

OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
      public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
       //nothing here, do I have to put anything?
      }
    };
preferencias.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);

getPrefs();
changefont(fuente, letra);
if (boole == true) {fontcolors();}

private void getPrefs(){
      fuente = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets() , preferencias.getString("elegirfuente", "fonts/Default.ttf"));
     letra = Integer.parseInt(preferencias.getString("fontstyle", "0"));
     bol = preferencias.getBoolean("randomcolors", true);
 }
```

I have nothing put in preference activity, do i have to put anything?

Also, do I have to edit this?: `(SharedPreferences prefs, String key)` I ask this because i havent created `prefs` and `key` varibles

Thanks in advance!!! ;)

EDIT1: Added preference activity

```
     public class PantallaOpciones extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.opciones);
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to use SharedPreferences like follows:

```
String PREFS_NAME = "com.example.sp", PREFS_TEST = "com.examples.sp.test";
SharedPreferences preferences;

preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
// This is how you instantiate a SharedPreference object.

preferences.edit().putString(PREFS_TEST,"TEST").commit();
// This way the preference is actually modified and saved.
```

Comment: thanks, but copy/pasted it and didnt work, do i have to edit it? where to put it??

Comment: The first three lines should go where you initialize your activity, within OnCreate() and the other one commits the changes and you should use it wherever you want the changes to happen.

Comment: Can you show the piece of code you use to update your preferences?

Comment: The thing is, I don't see where you modify them in your code. There's only access to them and the OnPreferencesChanged does nothing

Comment: Added edit1 in first message.... If this is not what you say, I havent more code related to preferences... Maybe something is missing... Sorry but I am a ToTaLn00b ;)

Comment: A ver que no estás modificando nunca las preferencias. Por qué no haces una actividad normal en vez de una preference activity?

Comment: porque he aprendido desde esta pagina http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/?p=2149 , por favor ayudame o mandame un enlace util o algo!!! ;)

Comment: Para lo que tu dices, seria crear una activity normal y corriente, con su layout y eso??? Vale, eso lo se hacer, pero si transfiero la información con un intent, como hqgo para que se actualicen los ajustes?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo de dos maneras, los puedes modificar desde la actividad que lanza el intent o puedes modificarlos en el receiver del intent. Yo lo haría en la que lo lanza.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! La que lo lanza es la actividad de las preferencias( quiero decir, donde va el checkbox y todo eso)?

Comment: A ver si te he ayudado vótame hahahaha Sí sí, hazlo en esa actividad. Supón que tienes varios checkbox y eso lo tomas como variables booleanas dentro de las SharedPreferences. Entonces cada vez que se presione un checkbox le das a preferences.edit().putBoolean(PREFS_CHK).commit(). Y ahí vas a estar guardando el estado.

Comment: Y despues de eso se me actualizara sola la aplicacion o tendre que crear un listener?porque igual se cambia la preferencia, pero luego puede que no lea el intent automaticamente...

Comment: Ya estaría lista, la próxima vez que arranques si verificas el valor de la preferencia será el último que modificaste.

Comment: Pero es que el problema es ese, que quiero que los cambios tengan efecto sin salir del programa

Comment: Usando lo que te dije tendrán efecto inmediatamente. Si necesitas que el efecto se vea en otra actividad necesitas hace un broadcast intent y en el receiver actualizar los cambios extrayéndolos de las preferencias. Oye que me voy a dormir, comenta y mañana me lo veo.